# CSS radio-button transition not working only on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, radio-button, transition

could anyone help me... below is a simple example of my problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    #layer1 {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    }
    #layer2 {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    }
    #on:checked + label + input + #layer1 {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #on:checked + label + input + div + #layer2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #off:checked + #layer1 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #off:checked + #layer1 + #layer2 {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for"on">ON</label>
    <input checked type="radio" id="on" name="switch" />
    <label for"off">OFF</label>
    <input type="radio" id="off" name="switch" />
    <div id="layer1">This is layer1</div>
    <div id="layer2">This is layer2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically I'm creating a fading switch effect that works without javascript. This transition effect is working on FF, IE, Chrome, Opera, but not on Safari (my version is 5.1.7). I'm aware of different prefixes (-moz, -ms..., but it doesn't change anything). Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code, but it doesn't work in IE9 (no transition effect), Chr25 (layer2 never appears) and FF31 (no transition effect). It only works in Chr36. Maybe you want to solve those problems first?

Comment: @Frank Conijn For simplicity I have stated only Webkit notation (for Safari and Chrome) so that is the reason why no other browser cannot handle it (adding `transition: all ease 1s;` under webkit notation will make it work for others). As I said, I know about the -ms- or -moz- prefixes. This is really a bug of Safari I assume. In addition I found out that it doesn't have to do with transition effect. Safari cannot make it work either way while using `checked`. Apple really missed here something. For me this is major bug and nobody seems to solve or deal with it. Strange.

Comment: Admitted, without the declarations for Firefox it shouldn't work in it. But without it, it should still work in IE9 and Chr25, shouldn't it? I like to solve coding puzzles, but not when the eventual solution is not used after all because basic browser support is lacking.

Comment: Don't know quite what do you mean. If there is `-webkit-...` notation it is supported only by Safari and Chrome (browsers with webkit render core). Nor IE9 nor Firefox understand it and they will ignore it. IE9 this code handles well, just ignores the transition and makes an immediate switch. But this is not solving my problem. I still don't know why this simple `:checked` function doesn't work in Safari. This is an important function as it substitutes a click function if Javascript is off. I would really need to solve it for Safari, other browsers work as expected.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I added all transition declarations, so it should work in all browsers. But apart from IE9 (no transition effect) it doesn't work in Chr25 either: layer 2 never appears. As is in the case in Saf 5.1.7 on Win Vista. That's what I mean with "basic browser support is lacking." I don't see any problem with the `checked`.

Comment: Regarding `checked`: that would only work in HTML5. For other doctypes, the syntax would be `checked="checked"`.